# Plotly.extendTraces only work with two traces but not with three

Tags: javascript, charts, plotly

```
function getData() {
  return Math.random();
};

function plotGraph(graph_div) {
  let UPDATE_INTERVAL = 300;

  Plotly.plot(graph_div, [{
    y: [1, 2, 3].map(getData),
    name: 'x',
    mode: 'lines',
    line: { color: '#80CAF6' }
  }, {
    y: [1, 2, 3].map(getData),
    name: 'y',
    mode: 'lines',
    line: { color: '#DF56F1' }
  }, {
    y: [1, 2, 3].map(getData),
    name: 'z',
    mode: 'lines',
    line: { color: '#4D92E9' }
  }]);

  var cnt = 0;

  var interval = setInterval(function () {
    var time = new Date();

    Plotly.extendTraces(graph_div, {
      y: [[getData()], [getData()], [getData()]]
    }, [0, 1])

    cnt = cnt+1;
    if (cnt === 100) clearInterval(interval);
  }, UPDATE_INTERVAL);

}
```

error:

```
plotly-latest.min.js:7 Uncaught Error: attribute y must be an array of length equal to indices array length
    at plotly-latest.min.js:7
    at R (plotly-latest.min.js:7)
    at Object.t [as extendTraces] (plotly-latest.min.js:7)
    at realtime_vis.js:40
```

point to

```
Plotly.extendTraces(graph_div, {
      y: [[getData()], [getData()], [getData()]]
    }, [0, 1])
```

Example from official documentation only shows how plot 2 lines, but that example not working with three lines.
Any help? I assume that I can explicitly specify the size of the array?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Plotly documentation isn't really clear [here](https://plot.ly/javascript/plotlyjs-function-reference/#plotlyextendtraces) but the third parameter is an array of plot indexes you want to modify.

In your case you are telling Plotly to modify `[0, 1]` but you provide 3 new y-values. If you change it to `[0, 1, 2]` it should work, or you could provide only two new y-values.

```js
function getData() {
  return Math.random();
};

Plotly.plot(graph_div, [{
 y: [1, 2, 3].map(getData),
 name: 'x',
 mode: 'lines',
 line: { color: '#80CAF6' }
}, {
 y: [1, 2, 3].map(getData),
 name: 'y',
 mode: 'lines',
 line: { color: '#DF56F1' }
}, {
 y: [1, 2, 3].map(getData),
 name: 'z',
 mode: 'lines',
 line: { color: '#4D92E9' }
}]);

var cnt = 0;

var interval = setInterval(function () {
 var time = new Date();

 Plotly.extendTraces(graph_div, {
  y: [[getData()], [getData()], [getData()]]
 }, [0, 1, 2])

 cnt = cnt+1;
 if (cnt === 100) clearInterval(interval);
}, 300);
```

```html
<head>
  <script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="graph_div"></div>
</body>
```